# PDF JavaScript: Функция с циклом

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы, pdf, label

Имеется следующий код, который выявляет лэйбы в PDF докумене при совпдении значений. Проблема в том, что только появлеятся первая лейба, в примере указал две но появляется только первая. В моем коде порядка 40 if...else синтаксисов, в некоторых мне нужно выявлять по 8 лейбов за раз. Я загнал все лэйбы в массив `fields` и потом скрываю и показываю их в документе в зависимости от выбора пользователем в форме значения, если значения совпали то показать определенные лэйбы а все остальные скрыть. Был бы очень благодарен если кто нибудь подсказал что не так с кодом и как его можно изменить?

```js
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("countryofgrowth").value;
var type = this.getField("type").value;

var AcceptableCountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", "Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]"];

function setDisplay(item)
{
        var fields = ["sugarlabel", "goodsugar", "sugarQualitylevellow" /*,...*/];
    for(var i=0; i< fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i] == item) {
                getField(fields[i]).display=display.visible;
        } else {
                getField(fields[i]).display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}

if (type == "sugar" && AcceptableCountries.indexOf(countryofgrowth) != -1)
{
    setDisplay("sugarlabel")
    setDisplay("goodsugar")
}
```

Приблизительно вот так выглядит моя форма. В каждом выпадающем меню пользователь выбирает значения и при совпадении опеределенных значений, в докумнте должны поевляться определенные лэйбы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретезируй пожалуйста - отредактируй пост: чем ты вытягиваешь из pdf данные, какая библиотека используется. Не ясно, что значит "синтаксис и его совпадения". Ну и явный косяк - в одном месте у тебя вызывается `this.getField` во втором просто `getField` это разные вызовы.

Comment: Здаравствуйте Александр, изменил пост и надеюсь сейчас ситация более ясна. Буду благодарен вашей помощи.

Comment: Я тебе могу подсказать мало, т.к. не знаю даже библиотеку, которую ты используешь для чтения pdf. Как минимум повторюсь про ошибку `this.getField` сверху, внутри ф-ии просто `getField`: надо перед ф-ей сделать `var self = this;` и внутри ф-ии вызывать `self.getField(...) `. И тут как-бы не просят код за тебя отлаживать - как это делать написано в соответсвующих статьях, и можно попросить сделать на других порталах. Тут задают концептуальные вопросы, которые не гуглятся даже на английском языке.

Comment: Александр, я не использую не какую библиотеку, код находиться в самом документе. Я не профи в програмировании, и тем более в javascript. Я думал тут помогают решать проблемы с кодом, не уверен как можно помочь с проблемой не написав код разрешающий проблему, я больше других форумов и не знаю, этот самый популярный потому здесь и написал. Я сверху написал весь концепт моего кода, не уверен о какой библиотеке идет речь... Направьте хотя бы в нужном направлении?